# What is /storage/emulated/0/?

Tags: android, filesystems

Recently, I've figured out that if I delete files from `/sdcard/Download` it deletes files from `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. And if I add the files into `/sdcard/Download` it duplicates then in `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.

So what is `/storage/emulated/0/`? For what purposes do we have it in our android file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I remember, this confusion arises due to keeping older paths for backwards compatibility. Basically, none of your files are getting duplicated, because both `/sdcard/Download` and `/storage/emulated/0/Download` point to the exact same location. The `/0/` here is for the multi-user feature introduced in JB, and refers to the main user. If you had one more user, it'd be `/1/` for that particular user, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Well, everything is pretty simple. /sdcard/Download is just a simlink (shortcut) to downloads folder and /storage/emulated/0/Download is actual path to folder.